# After generating divs using php for loop and also dynamically assigning for them ids how to i target the ids using jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

Am using a while loop to out various  elements each containing rows from a mysql database. I was able to make each div have different id however, i have no idea how i can target each of the divs usings jquery through the ids so that each div is a clickable link.
Here is a part of my code

```
 <!-- php script -->
 <?php
   require_once 'controllers/fetchVids.php';

   if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
       // output data of each row
       while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
           $fileName = $row[$filePath];
           $file = basename($fileName);
           $mb = round($row[$size] / (1000000), 2);

           echo "
                <div class='container search-output' id=''>
                    <div class='row song-info' id='file-$row[$videoId]'>
                        <div class= 'col col-sm-6 artist'>
                            $file
                        </div>
                    <div class= 'col col-sm-3 song-title'>
                        <span>Size:</span>
                        $mb mb
                    </div>
                    <div class= 'col col-sm-3 song-title'>
                       <span>Downloads:</span>
                       $row[$downloads]
                    </div>
             </div>

                <div class='row-lower'>
                   <a href='#' class='icon all-links'>
                       <i class='fa fa-whatsapp'></i> Share
                   </a>
                       <i class='fa fa-clock duration'></i> Duration $row[$duration] mins
               </div>
                               
              </div> 
             ";
       } else {
            echo "No New Videos";
            }

        mysqli_close($connection);
       ?>
```

Someone please show me the right jquery to do the above. thank you
Below is the jquery code i tried but it rather opens all the divs and not only that that a user clicks on

```js
$(document).on('click', '.song-info', function() {
  // alert(this.id);
  if (this.id) {
    window.location = "./song-details.php";
  }
});
```

Comment: var el = $("#divid");  Basically, the jQuery selector follows css selector syntax.

Comment: What you've tried so far ..Please provide your js code

Comment: Post the jQuery code you attempted. SO is not a coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you were going wrong by using the 'this' keyword - you may have wanted to use $(this) instead, which is a keyword in jQuery that gives the DOM node you are currently working on access to jQuery methods (at least as far as I understand it!)

You can use $(this).attr('attribute name') (another jQuery method) to get the 'id' property of the div you clicked and use it within your function.

There are more than a few ways to do this, as mentioned in the comments, but here is how I would go about it. I'm assuming you want to send the fileId in a query string to './song-details.php'.

```
  $(document).on('click', '.song-info', function() {
    let id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop()
      if (id) {
        window.location = "./song-details.php" + "?id=" + id
      }
  })
```

Comment: thank you for the code its able to pick out the id and show it in the url, however it still opens all the available divs generated using the while loop. Is there a way i can modify this jquery code to open exactly n only the div with that id that the user has clicked on>

Comment: what do you mean by 'opens'?

Comment: Thank You. My bug was coming from else where which i was able to fix. Your code just worked perfectly